# Magento 1.6, allow SKU's to be used in catalog promotion rules

Tags: magento

I'd like to set up catalog price rules discounts based on SKU.

However when I go to 'manage attributes' and try to edit SKU to 'use in Promo Rules: yes'.  I get an error saying that SKU is a system reserved atrribute.

I have already changed the SKU attribute to user_defined=1 under eav_attribute table, but the message still appears.

It seems this was possible in earlier version of magento but not 1.6?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I took a guess and managed to fix my own problem.

I had set SKU attribute to user_defined=1 under eav_attribute table earlier on along with every other attribute.  I had assumed setting them all to '1' would make life easier in the future.  However, setting SKU user_defined to 0 via phpmyadmin, actually allowed me to make the changes I wanted.